# dropping characters from regular expression groups

Tags: regex

The goal: I want to convert a number from the format "10.234,56" to "10234.56"

Using this simple approach almost gets us there

```
/([\d\.]+),(\d\d)/ => '\1.\2'
```

The problem is that the first group of the match (of course) still contains the '.' character.

So questions are:

1. Is it possible to exclude a character from the group somehow?
2. How would you solve this with a single regexp

(I know this is a trivial problem when not using a single regexp)

Comment: As in practice numbers are somewhat limited in that use case I ended up using /(\d*)\.?(\d*)\.?(\d+),(\d\d)/ => '\1\2\3.\4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to do this and I went the easier route

> As in practice numbers are somewhat limited in that use case I ended
>   up using /(\d*).?(\d*).?(\d+),(\d\d)/ => '\1\2\3.\4'

Answer (score 1):

Why use regexp at all? Just replace the `'.'` with `''` and then the `','` with `'.'`.

Comment: "I know this is a trivial problem when not using a single regexp"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the dots instead ([Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/mzGPTekB0L)):

```
/\.(?=[\d.]+,\d\d)/ => ''
```

If you only want to remove dots that appear to be thousand separators ([Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/hxfX48hwas)):

```
/\.(?=\d{3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d\d)/
```

Comment: The dot needs to be replaced into a comma, too.

Comment: @tucrudt: I doubt that can be done in a single regular expression for the general case (unlimited length numbers).